# Loading data on a UIViewController: viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear - What is the proper logic?

Tags: iphone, ios, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I have a tabBarControllerView with a UIScrollViewController in its third tab. I'm loading essentially the same thing, pictures from core data, in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear. I'm thinking that viewWillAppear is what I can use to update the view in UIScrollView. The only thing is when I add pictures to core data the correct picture isn't being displayed.

I'm wondering if it's my viewWillAppear logic or if my context is off? I'm working on fixing my context so if my logic is sound (minus the ManagedObjectContext) then that will be great to hear - as I can go back to working on the context issue.

If it's the logic then I'd really appreciate if you could point out my flaw(s) :-)

Header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PhotoViewController.h"

@interface MyTabBarViewController  : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{

    IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    UIImage *image;
    CGFloat scrollWidth;
    int pageNumber;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;

-(IBAction)clickPageControl:(id)sender;

@end
```

Implementation file ... relevant snippets

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scroller.delegate=self;
    scroller.pagingEnabled=YES;
    scroller.directionalLockEnabled=YES;
    scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(pageControl.numberOfPages*scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height);
    scrollWidth = 0;
    pageNumber = 0;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(CoreDataProjAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchCount = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    int pageCount = [fetchCount count];
    for (int i=pageNumber; i<pageCount; i++)
    {
        PhotoViewController *pvc = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil];
        CGRect rect = scroller.frame;
        rect.size.height = scroller.frame.size.height;
        rect.size.width = scroller.frame.size.width;
        rect.origin.x = scroller.frame.origin.x + scrollWidth;
        rect.origin.y = scroller.frame.origin.y;
        pvc.view.frame  = rect;
        [pvc view];
        pvc.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pageNumber];
        pvc.label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        Photo *photo = [[Photo alloc] init];
        photo = [fetchCount objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImage *fetchedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:photo.photo];
        pvc.imageView.image = fetchedImage;
        [scroller addSubview:pvc.view];
        [pvc release];
        pageNumber++;
        scrollWidth += scroller.frame.size.width;
    }
    pageControl.numberOfPages=pageCount;
    pageControl.currentPage=0;
    [self.view addSubview:scroller];
    [request release];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    scroller.delegate=self;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(CoreDataProjAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchCount = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    int pageCount = [fetchCount count];
    scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(pageCount*scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height);
    for (int i=pageNumber; i<pageCount; i++)
    {
        PhotoViewController *pvc = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil];
        CGRect rect = scroller.frame;
        rect.size.height = scroller.frame.size.height;
        rect.size.width = scroller.frame.size.width;
        rect.origin.x = scroller.frame.origin.x + scrollWidth;
        rect.origin.y = scroller.frame.origin.y;
        pvc.view.frame  = rect;
        [pvc view];
        pvc.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pageNumber];
        pvc.label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        Photo *photo = [[Photo alloc] init];
        photo = [fetchCount objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImage *fetchedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:photo.photo];
        pvc.imageView.image = fetchedImage;
        [scroller addSubview:pvc.view];
        [pvc release];
        pageNumber++;
        scrollWidth += scroller.frame.size.width;
    }
    pageControl.numberOfPages=pageCount;
    pageControl.currentPage=0;
    [self.view addSubview:scroller];
    [request release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the actual cause, but one thing I notice is that in your for loop, you are manually incrementing `pageNumber++` and I'm not entirely sure why.  If you take any internal reference of `pageNumber` in the loop (I only see the line where you're setting the label text offhand) and replace that with `i`, I believe this should let you display your images properly.  In short, just take `pageNumber` out of the code (unless there's something I'm clearly overlooking) and just use `for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {`.  If nothing more, this will give you more control over your loop and eliminate any varying changes during each loop increment.  As for which method to use, it's most likely best to implement the code in `viewWillAppear` since it will give the view more of a chance to load and give you proper dimensions when you display your images.

EDIT: If you're looking to display the images in a certain order, you won't be able to do that directly by fetching the objects from the managedObjectContext since it stores its objects as an NSSet (unindexed).  If you want to display the pictures in a particular order, you will need to use a sort descriptor.  So when you're creating your request, you'll want to follow something like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(CoreDataProjAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSError *error = nil;
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"someAttributeToIndex" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];
NSArray *fetchCount = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Doing this should let you actually specify the order which you want to present the images, either by date added or an integer index (which you will have to add as an attribute to the entity)

Comment: I'm going to try your suggestion. But the reason I chose not to use i in the loop is because if there are 2 objects in core data to start and then on the reload there are 5 objects then I want to start the loop on page 3 (5-2). So I might be off in my thinking but that's why I was going with page numbers because it should be on 3 (or whatever number).

Comment: No, that didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though slev :-)

Comment: Oh, I see.  In that case, I can certainly see your logic to keep the pages ordered with the correct amount of images.  I'm not sure I really see any reason why the images are off.  Are you calling the code in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`? At the first run, it's possible they're running into each other, skewing what pictures are going where.  Also, you might run into memory leaks when you're setting your Photo objects.  I'd either release the Photo *photo once you've set the new image or instead of alloc/init, just call `Photo *photo = [fetchCount objectAtIndex:i]`

Comment: thanks again Slev. i fixed the memory leak :-) glad you pointed that out. And yeah i still don't know why this isn't working. i think the ManagedObjectContext has something to do with it. i'm going to continue playing around with that.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of something.  Though after typing it out, this will be too long for the comment, so I'm going to edit my original answer to put it in there.  I THINK this might be what's giving you problems

Comment: Lol, OK I'm getting closer to the answer. Your suggestion for setting int to i instead of pageNumber revealed the error :-) So what's happening is this: Say I add PhotoA to core data. It's in and shows up fine. Now Say I add PhotoB to core data. It's in but it shows as two PhotoA's. And this is because my original view of just PhotoA isn't getting replaced or removed. Instead I have PhotoB hanging off the end of the screen/outside of scroller.contentsize. Can I just replace the existing subview with the new ones? Or do I need to remove the old subviews? Thanks again for all your help @slev

Comment: You should be able to replace the existing subview without any altercations, so long as you can get a reference to them.  If you use `UIImageView`s to hold you images, that could potentially make it even easier since you'd only need to set the image property to the new image

Comment: I think I was taking the lazy way out by trying to remove the view. I'm just going to do a sort on the fetch request like you originally mentioned :-)

Comment: It will probably make life a bit easier in the long run, but hopefully you'll be able to get it working to your liking

Comment: My pleasure =].  Glad all is up and running